defectdojo ldap integration not connected
I want to connect defectdojo (docker compose) to ldap (active directory), I have follwed the documentation https://documentation.defectdojo.com/dev/integrations/ldap-authentication/ and https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/groups.html and changed values as needed
however I can't verify if a connection has happened or not, the logs doesn't show anything regarding ldap
when I try to enter one of the users it doesn't login.
I just want to know where can I find the logs for ldap to edit my configs accordingly. thank you
